# How to start deployment with email authentication in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

We have a CI jenkins platform and we want to manage our deployments with an email confirmation. A user send a request to the deployment plan for starting. But in the first step, the plan send an email confirmation to an administrator. If the admin click the request link, deployment will be start, otherwise wont start.

Is there a way to do this with jenkins or any jenkins plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is a way to do that, honestly, more than one way to do that and you can choose by your preferneces. What I will suggest you is to consider the way explained in the issues of Jenkins https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33793

though it have status Unresolved, but it looks like by my knowledge that it will work even right now , cause it is just an URL.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply, this looks like what I want.

Comment: Is there a simple example for this task?

Comment: create ```input``` step in your jenkins pipeline or job and when execute it manually for one time and then I bet you can copy the url of ```proceed``` when the job will ask you to click on button